# Flutter: conditional with nested Map inside the List

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List aa = [
  {'live': true, 'name': 'John', 'code': 1},
  {'live': false, 'name': 'Doe',  'code': 2},
];
```

I have the List called `aa` like above. I want to make it conditional using that. Firstly, I want to check the code is 1 and then look for `live`'s boolean value to display a `Text` widget.

```
 aa.where((e) => e['code'] == 1).where((e) => e['live'])
              ? Text('alive!?')
              : Text('not alive!?'),
```

This gives me an error. Prob because it is returning the Map value not true or false value. How can I take out `live` value to use it for the conditional return in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simplify @Benyamin's solution, you can use following code:

```
for (var item in aa.where((e) => e['code'] == 1)) item['live']
                ? Text("alive!?")
                : Text("not alive!?")
```

Comment: It important to note that the above code makes sense only as a collection-`for` element within a `List` or `Set` literal.

Answer (score 4):

Do it using a for loop and it will work:

```
for (var i in aa) {
  if(i['code'] == 1) {
    if(i['live']) {
      //YOUR WIDGET HERE
    } else {
      //YOUR WIDGET HERE
    }
  }
}
```